# spark : key already cancelled error with mapPartition

Tags: apache-spark

I'm writing a program that update a cassandra table.

I've writen a first shot where I update the table row by row from a rdd through a map.

Now I want to build a batch of updates using the same kind of syntax as in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spark-users/LUb7ZysYp2k/MhymcFddb8cJ):

But as soon as I use a *mapPartition* I get a 
`Key already cancelled error.`

The program updates the table properly but it seems that the problem appears when the driver tries to shut down the resources.

```
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at CustomerIdReconciliation.scala:143, took 1.998601568 s 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://cim1-dev:4044
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev2,52516) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev2,52516) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev2,52516) not found 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7cedcb23 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7cedcb23 
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException 
   at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:386) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@38e8c534 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@38e8c534 java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException 
   at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:310) 
       at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev,44773) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev3,29293) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev3,29293) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@159adcf5 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@159adcf5 java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException 
   at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:386) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev,44773) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(cim1-dev,44773) not found 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@329a6d86 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@329a6d86 java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException 
   at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:310) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139) 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@3d3e86d5 
15/01/26 00:07:00 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@3d3e86d5 java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException 
   at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:310) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:139) 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterActor: MapOutputTrackerActor stopped! 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO ConnectionManager: Selector thread was interrupted! 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO ConnectionManager: ConnectionManager stopped 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon. 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports. 
15/01/26 00:07:01 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

I've tried to set these 2 options but it doesn't change anything:

```
set("spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout","600") 
set("spark.akka.frameSize","50")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's some kind of bug in Spark for sure.  What happens when you try using 1.2.0?